# MySql - Remove data after 3 months

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have MySql Database with 2 table:
Events
History

They have the same columns.

the first thing i want to do is to move all event that was passed to history and i achive it with :

```
@"INSERT INTO history (clientid, startdate, enddate, first, city) " +
            "SELECT clientid, startdate, enddate, first, city " +
            "FROM events " +
            "WHERE startdate < now()";
```

This work perfect.

Now i want to delete from history the rows that the startdate passed 3 months ago.
How i can implement it?

Comment: do you want to delete 3 months older records?

Comment: Yes . 3 months older then startdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just compare the start date with actual date minus 3 months (using [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub))

```
delete from history
where start_date < DATE_SUB(now(), interval 3 month)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mysql Event scheduler as below:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 MONTHS
    DO
      //your query
```

For more information you can see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html